# Getting all output data form console when running process with Apache Commons Exec

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, apache-commons-exec

The thing is... I'm running a process with the `DefaultExecutor` class of `org.apache.commons.exec` libraries. Like this:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine("java");
    DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
    exec.setExitValue(1);
    exec.execute(cmd);
}
```

I need to take that output "on the run" with another thread, to log it elsewhere. What is the best way of accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `PipedOutputStream` and a `PipedInputStream`. You can find an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956323/capturing-large-amounts-of-output-from-apache-commons-exec). Don't forget to [`close` your streams.](http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/whats-this-ioexception-write-end-dead/)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at `log4j`, a rather useful project from Apache. In a project I was recently working on, `log4j` was used to put all of the logs from various threads into one convenient file. Just make sure that you construct the logger in such as way that only one instance of it is available, and this should solve your problem.

Unfortunately, I was only an intern, and was not present when the team set up the logging system, so I can't actually help you with configuration. Luckily the project's [website](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) appears to have plenty of documentation to help you out.

Comment: I know how to log it, but I need to get the String from the console before.